# How can I predict a single value from a linear regression in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I've made a linear regression of dollar prices to GDPPC like so:

```
r = lm(dollar_value ~ GDPPC, prices_gdp)
```

(`prices_gdp` is a `data.table`, if that matters).

I can now easily generate a bunch of values based on a `data.table` using `predict`. But what I want to do (in order to plot a `geom_abline` on a chart) is calculate the dollar value when GDPPC is zero, and get that back as a number—something *like*

```
predict(r, 0)
```

This gives me an error: `Error in eval(predvars, data, env): object 'GDPPC' not found`. Is there any way of doing this short of creating a new dummy `data.table` with GDPPC=0 as its only row, feeding it in, and then pulling the number out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just create the same data table and put the regressor GDPPC to zero. Try:

```
predict(r, data.frame(GDPPC = 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function which extracts the name of the term in the model and makes the call to predict for you.

```
preds <- function(o, vals){
  #' Make prediction from simple linear regression
  #'
  #' Makes a prediction from a simple linear regression without
  #' needing to manually create a data.frame.  This will fail
  #' on models with more than one predictor.
  #' @param o The lm object to use to make predictions
  #' @param vals The values to make predictions for.
  dat <- setNames(data.frame(vals), as.character(formula(o)[[3]]))
  predict(o, newdata = dat)
}
```

and using it...

```
> o <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
> preds(o, 1:3)
       1        2        3 
31.94065 26.59618 21.25171
```

Comment: Comments are ready to be viewed via `?preds` if you load the docstring package beforehand.